# not able to position the correlated image on top of orginal image using normxcorr2 matlab function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to locate the exact location of the subimage of an image using normxcorr2 matlab function. It seems to work all well except placing the image at exact location.

The full image is this [image: full image]

The subimage is this [image: part of the image]

I am find xpeak and ypeak of the correlation of two images and displaying them both using these two coordinates. But for unknown reason, it is not at the location it is supposed to be.

The output looks like this [image: resultant image]

My code is as follows

```
clear
clc
%#read & convert the image
imgGray  = imread('1.jpg');
imgGray = rgb2gray(imgGray);
obj     = rgb2gray(imread('2.jpg'));




%# cross-correlate and find the offset
cor          = normxcorr2(obj,imgGray); 
[max_cc,indx]       = max(abs(cor(:))); %# Modify for multiple instances (generalize)
[yPeak, xPeak] = ind2sub(size(cor),indx(1));
offset     = [yPeak - size(obj,1), xPeak - size(obj,2)]; 

% size(obj,2)
% create a mask
xbegin = offset(1)+1;
xend = offset(1)+size(obj,2);
ybegin = offset(2)+1;
yend = offset(2)+size(obj,1);
mask      = uint8(zeros(size(imgGray)));
mask(ybegin:yend,xbegin:xend) = obj;




h1 = imshow(imgGray);
set(h1,'AlphaData',0.7)
hold on
h2= imshow(mask);
set(h2,'AlphaData',0.9)
```

Please suggest something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've swapped x and y. `offset` is defined as `[y, x]`, but you've used it as `[x, y]`. I've pointed out these lines below:

```
offset     = [yPeak - size(obj,1), xPeak - size(obj,2)];
```

and then

```
xbegin = offset(1)+1;
xend = offset(1)+size(obj,2);
ybegin = offset(2)+1;
yend = offset(2)+size(obj,1);
```